# Project Euler #1

Tags: javascript

I only started programming about three days ago and I've been working with Javascript. I've been trying to tackle Project Euler [Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1):

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

And I feel like my program should work, but my answer is still slightly off. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
var threeSum = [];
var threeTotal = 0;
var fiveSum = [];
var fiveTotal = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) {
    threeSum.push(i);
}
for (j = 0; j < threeSum.length; j++) {
    threeTotal = threeTotal + threeSum[j];
}
for (a = 0; a < 1000; a += 5) {
    fiveSum.push(a);
}
for (r = 0; r < fiveSum.length; r++) {
    fiveTotal = fiveTotal + fiveSum[r];
}
console.log(threeTotal + fiveTotal);
```

I get an answer of 266333 when I run this program.

Comment: Imagine we don't know what Project Euler #1 is. How would we answer this?

Comment: Similar question with explained solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000

Answer (score 2):

The task of [Project Euler #1](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1) is

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

not

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 below 1000 and all multiples of 5 below 1000.

Numbers like 45 that are multiples of both 3 and 5 should not be counted twice.

Answer (score 2):

Side note - programming often also means searching for non-obvious solution. The wording of the question suggests looping of the numbers from 1 to 999 but with a bit of math no looping is required at all and you can solve the problem for n = 1.000.000.000 as fast as for n = 10 (if nothing overflows).

```
var n = 1000;

var multiplesOfThree        = Math.floor((n - 1) /  3);
var multiplesOfFive         = Math.floor((n - 1) /  5);
var multiplesOfThreeAndFive = Math.floor((n - 1) / 15);

var sum =  3 * multiplesOfThree        * (multiplesOfThree        + 1) / 2
        +  5 * multiplesOfFive         * (multiplesOfFive         + 1) / 2
        - 15 * multiplesOfThreeAndFive * (multiplesOfThreeAndFive + 1) / 2;
```

Comment: You may want to write a correct answer for the tagged language, especially considering how similar to Javascript your code is.

Comment: I wanted to keep the noise level low but it is not to bad especially because the sum needs no floors.

Answer (score 0):

[Project Euler 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) is

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the
>   sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Since you're learning, I'm assuming you don't want an explicit answer to this.

Think about what you're summing. The first few terms of the 3 loop are

```
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

and the first few terms of the 5 loop are

```
[5, 10, 15]
```

Since you are counting the multiples of both 3 and 5 twice, your answer is larger than it should be

Answer (score 0):

```
this is pretty much how I did it and I get the right answer. 

`var threeSum=0;` 
 var fiveSum=0;
 var dSum=0;

for (var b=3; b<1000; b++) {

     if (b%3===0) {
        threeSum=threeSum+b; 

     }
}

for (var c=5; c<1000; c++) {
    if (c%5===0) {
       fiveSum=fiveSum+c;


    }
}

for  (var d=15; d<1000; d++) {
       if (d%15===0) {
          dSum=dSum+d;

    }

}
console.log((threeSum+threeSum)-dSum);
```

Comment: That might be a correct answer, but the question was what was wrong with the original poster's answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution to Project Euler 1st problem, simple and very easy to understand. It's in java, but it can be easily translated to any language

```
public class Multiples {

    public static int multiplesSum(int n1, int n2, int limit) {
        int sum = 0;
        int n = Math.min(n1, n2);
        for(int i=n; i<limit; i++) {
            if(i%n1==0 || i%n2==0) {
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = multiplesSum(3,5,1000);
        System.out.println("Total sum is: " + total);
    }

}
```

And here it is the best solution as suggested by Project Euler experts:

```
/**
 * Remember that the sum of the first n natural numbers is: n(n+1)/2
 * 
 * Let’s look at the details of our function and take as example n=3.
    We would have to add:
    3+6+9+12+......+999=3*(1+2+3+4+...+333)
    For n=5 we would get:
    5+10+15+...+995=5*(1+2+....+199)
    Now note that 199=995/5 but also 999/5 rounded down to the nearest integer.
 * 
 * @param n
 * @param limit
 * @return
 */
public static int multiplesSumOf(int n, int limit) {
    int target = (limit-1)/n;               
    return n * target*(target+1)/2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int total = multiplesSumOf(3,1000) + multiplesSumOf(5,1000) - multiplesSumOf(15,1000);
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted my solution using Kotlin here:
https://github.com/moxi/project-euler-solutions/blob/master/code/src/main/kotlin/org/rcgonzalezf/onetoten/Problem1.kt
The nice thing about Kotlin and why I'm posting here is that they support JavaScript compilation(transpilation) as well, so you might find it interesting: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/kotlin-to-javascript/kotlin-to-javascript.html

```
fun solve(baseNumber: Int): Int {
    return (0..baseNumber - 1)
            .filter { it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0 }
            .sum()
}
```

As you can see is very concise, I'm going to try to solve some of the Euler Project problems Streaming on LiveEdu I think it will be fun, I don't want to paste the link here since this is not an advertisement platform, if you want to discuss about it search for Project Euler over there.

Answer (score -1):

```
var num = 1000
var numbers = []

for(var i = 0;  i < num; i++){
  if( i % 3 === 0|| i % 5 === 0){
     numbers.push(i)
  }
};

var sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```